# SSL Handshake between Java Server with Netty Frame and C# Client with dotnetasyncsocket

Tags: c#, java, certificate, netty, handshake

The client can receive the certificate from the server with ***remotecertificatechain*** errors but the [java](/questions/tagged/java) server throws an error *null cert chain*.

I passed a `keystore` in java while I use a `.crt` certificate as to [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) client. I have imported my client certificate to server certificate.

I have noticed that during the handshake, when the java server accesses the `getAcceptedIssuers`, java netty servers throws an exceptioncaught:

```
WARNING: Unexpected exception from downstream.
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:262)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:320)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:785)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:100)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:465)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:359)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)....
```

Any idea why this is happening? Any suggestions to solve this? :(

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, turns out that there was no problem with the code! it's with the self signed certificate on the client side. I used keytool of java to make the self signed certificate but it didn't work when
i used this certificate on c# client using dotnetasyncsocket. So what I did was obtain a certificate signed by CA on http://cert.startcom.org/ that is for free.